# Why would you extend a class rather than just adding a new method to the original class?

Tags: php, oop, methods, extend

I finally had my Ah-ha moment when it came to classes in OOP. I've been struggling to get my mind around the idea. Now that I'm starting to get it I was wondering what the purpose of extending a class is. Would it not be simpler to just add another method into the class or am I just missing the point?

Comment: the purpose is to avoid repetition of code. And access all the methods of the mentioned class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add functionality to a class you add a method. However, there are situations that you want to add functionality, but cannot do that in a base class.

The best is show with a example. When adding a method `Radius` to a class makes only sense if the class is a `Circle`, a `Rect` has no radius. Adding a method `Radius` to the base class also makes no sense, because the `Rect` class then also gets a method `Radius`.

Example:

```
abstract class Shape
{
  abstract public function Draw();
}

class Rect extends Shape
{
  public function Draw()
  {
  }
}

class Circle extends Shape
{
  public function Draw()
  {
  }

  public function Radius()
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: I get where you are going with this... however would adding a draw method to the extended classes not defeat the purpose of draw in the shape class? Thereby making the whole reason (DRY coding) of extending classes pointless?

Comment: The draw method in the shape class should be abstract, there is no way to draw a Shape. I adjusted the example.

Comment: ok now it looks like I've got some more reading and understanding to do. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the original class is part of a library that you can't change.

Sometimes you want to extend a super class in multiple different ways.

For example (java syntax instead of PHP but the idea is the same):

```
class Shape {
  abstract double getArea();
}

class Square extends Shape {
  double getArea() {
    return size * size;
  }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  double getArea() {
    return radius * radius * Math.PI;
  }
}
```

To a method that accepts arguments of type Shape you can pass in Squares as well as Circles. The method doesn't need to know which one it gets but can still call getArea(). This wouldn't work if you simply added the method to the Shape class.

Comment: because it doesn't make sense for a square to have a getCircumference() method. Why is it now incorrect? It looks right to me. Your calculations in the methods are for area. Also, you've had three upvotes since I edited it (it was at -1).

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense? A sqaure's circumference is the sum of its sides. The area is the product of its sides. The calculations are for circumference, not area.

Comment: OK, that bit I was wrong about, but a square cannot have a [circumference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumference), maybe a perimeter length, but not a circumference.

Comment: I guess Perimeter would have been a better word. Still, the formulas are definitely not for area.

Comment: I changed the formulas. Mostly I was very surprised it's even possible to change someone else's answer. It's my first time here so I felt a bit violated :P. I'm learning as well.

Comment: You'll get used to it, see this for an explanation http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing . Between us you ended up with a good answer that got up voted 3 times, rather than your original one that had a down vote, probably because the down voter was confused by a square with a circumference.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a simplification, but to give you a real life example:

Consider that you were to create a content management system, i.e., a script to show different pages on your website based on user input.

You would probably want each page (let's call them modules) to have specific features, such as allowable commands to be executed when on that page/module. These different commands could then be different methods within each module class.

However, what if you were to allow a login command, no matter where the user was currently at in your website? i.e., this would be a command shared between all the modules.

Your solution to this could then be solved by having a parent module class, where the login method would reside, and be executable by all the modules.

```
// Your parent class
abstract class ParentModule 
{
   protected function login()
   {
      // Login stuff
   }
}

// One of your modules
final class ArticleModule extends ParentModule
{
    public function submit_article()
    {
        // An example function
    }
}

// Another one of your modules that the user could still login from
final class AnotherModule extends ParentModule
{
    public function another_command()
    {
        // Magic
    }
}
```

Your controller could then look something like the below.

```
$module = new ArticleModule();
$module->login();
$module->submit_article();
```

Lastly, when you get into looking at interfaces - took me forever to understand those - you will again see the benefit of abstract classes. And indeed, if you fully grasp the concept of abstract classes, you will more easily understand interfaces.